# iOS Tables - same code different colors on iPad vs iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikit

I have a very strange situation where it appears my coloring doesn't "stick" for iPad where as it does for iPhone.

## Iphone

[image]

## Ipad

[image]

Everything is done in storyboards - so I'm very confused as to why this is occurring.  Has anybody seen an issue like it before?

I cant seem to get rid of the white table rows in the iPad - its very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the old bug with UITableViewCell on the iPad.

Just use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```